# TeamCity switch between different VCS Roots (SVN and GIT) dynamically

Tags: teamcity

I got a project that is stored in svn and let's say mirrored in git.

Long story short: svn has bad connection, so we don’t branch in svn, use git through "git svn" to synchronize repositories and creating feature branches in git.

Earlier we got two build projects in TeamCity to handle that, but now I added few deploy projects that depends on a build artifacts, so I don’t want to duplicate them too.

In TeamCity, during the build I would like to prompt what VCS Root to use.
So, I added two VCS Roots, setup connections, setup checkout rules and set "VCS checkout mode" to "Do not checkout files automatically".

As I understand now I need to create a build step to manually checkout files from the chosen repository.

Is there something inside TeamCity that can allow me to reuse VCS Roots (and checkout rules) I already setup?
I mean is there any command that can checkout just by providing “VCS root ID”, or should I redefine all checkout rules completely on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approaches would be to utilize [conditional build steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-step-execution-conditions.html).

Set up two different build steps that perform manual checkout from each repository and execute them based on a parameter's value. You can then configure the parameter to have the 'Select' [type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/typed-parameters.html). Optionally, you can set its 'Display' value to 'Prompt' so that TeamCity will always ask you to select one of the pre-defined values.

Note that [checkout rules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/vcs-checkout-rules.html) won't directly affect manual checkout. They are only applied when [auto-checkout mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/vcs-checkout-mode.html) is used. They will still affect revisions that are attached to builds in the UI, though.

Another approach is to set up a simple [build chain](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-chain.html) by adding another build configuration in front of your main build config. The first build in the chain will perform a [REST API](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/teamcity-rest-api-documentation.html) call that [updates the checkout rules on both VCS roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/edit-build-configuration-settings.html) that are attached to the second config. You can set the `-:.` rule to a VCS Root that you don't want to be checked out. To make things simpler, you can store checkout rules in parameters, and assign these parameters to checkout rules of your VCS roots. The benefit of this approach is that you'll be able to use auto-checkout in your main build configuration. Again, you can utilize conditional build steps here to define which REST API call should be executed.

Comment: Am I understand right that REST API allows to set checkout mode for every VCS root separately? Because in UI there is only one checkout mode field which looks like applied for all attached VCS roots.

Comment: @mt_serg, I was a bit inaccurate with my answer. What I meant is that you can update _checkout rules_ for each VCS Root via a REST API call, not the checkout mode. [This article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/edit-build-configuration-settings.html) should help you with that. Checkout mode is indeed a setting that only exists on the build configuration level. 
Each VCS Root has its own [checkout policy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/git.html#git-checkout-policy) setting, but this is a different thing. Sorry for confusing you. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive answer, it's clear now.